# Can 'whole' be used as an adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, determiners

> It rained the whole week except on Sunday.

In this question is the word 'whole' an adverb? Or since the word 'week' is a noun, will it become a determiner?

Answer (score 2):

Since **whole** modifies the noun **week**, it is an adjective (but see below about determiners). Here are other sentences with an adjective modifying **week**:

> It rained all of **last** week except on Sunday.
>
> It rained twice during that **unpleasant** week.

Adverbs modify anything other than a noun: a verb, an adjective, a preposition, another adverb, or a whole clause or sentence.

A [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) is an adjective that specifies something about which instance or instances the noun refers to: a new instance not previously talked about (as indicated by **a**), an instance previously talked about (as indicated by **the**), the number of instances, the concept in general rather than any specific instance, etc. In your sentence, **whole** specifies how much of the instance is referred to, so it's usually [considered a determiner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/all-or-whole).

Some people don't count determiners as adjectives. I don't think it matters as long as you understand the difference between specifying which instance of the noun (as in "**last** week", "**the whole** week", and "**that** unpleasant week") and providing additional information about the instance ("that **unpleasant** week"). If you're asking in preparation for taking an exam, though, you should find out whether the author of the exam counts determiners as adjectives or not. If you're not sure, then bet that they consider them separate parts of speech.

Comment: Doesn't adverb answer questions on duration - how long?

Comment: @sailaja Yes, indicating duration is one function of adverbs. In your sentence, _the whole week_ is a noun phrase that functions as an adverb. Here is [another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/227673/6700) about this special use of nouns as adverbs to indicate duration.

Answer (score 1):

> **It rained the whole(entire) week except on Sunday**

In the sentence **whole** modifies **week** which  is a noun. So it is a an Adjective. It is not an adverb.An adverb usually does not modify a noun or a pronoun.It may modify a noun phrase or sometimes a whole sentence.

Comment: Believe it or not, there are one or two examples of an adverb modifying a noun, and of course adverbs can modify noun phrases.

Comment: @BillJ.I believe you and have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it *can* be an adverb - just not in your example sentence.

An adverb is a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb. In your example, it is modifying the noun "week".

For it to be an adverb, there would need to be another adjective or verb used, for example:

- It's a **whole new** ballgame.
- That's a **whole other** story.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that "whole" is modifying not the adjectives but the whole NPs and is thus an adjective.

Comment: I agree with you, @BillJ, but nonetheless "whole" can be an adverb - see the example in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

The word "whole" is certainly  used as an adverb. However, there are situations that this word is not acceptable as an adverb.

Comment: "Whole" as an adverb? Surely not.

Comment: @BillJ [At least one dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/whole#targetText=whole%20(adjective),whole%20(adverb)&targetText=whole%20wheat%20(adjective)) lists adverb forms, e.g. "swallow something whole." However, this answer suggests, without any explanation or examples, that it's commonly an adverb, and I think that's wrong.

Comment: @TypeIA  In "He swallowed the pie whole", I'd say that "whole" is an adjective functioning as an object complement referring to "pie".