# Is there any difference between the phrases "next month", "in the next month" and "for the next month"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between the phrases in the following sentences?

> I will work **next month**.
>
> I will work **in the next month**.
>
> I will work **for the next month**.

If I am right, *for the next* month means *throughout the next month*. But what about *in the next month*?
Is it even a valid phrase?

Answer (score 4):

> I will work **in the next month**.

means that the day or days when you will work will occur some time *within* the next month. Perhaps you will work on November 4, or from November 8 to November 12, or just on November 3, 8, 14, and 29. Or perhaps you will start your next job on November 10 and continue working **for** the rest of November and beyond.

> I will work **for the next month**.

means that you will work starting from approximately now or tomorrow, and the duration will be one month.

With [no preposition](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/227638/6700):

> I will work **next month**.

the meaning could be either "one or more times *within* November" or "the full duration of November". The context would need to indicate which meaning was intended, or it would be ambiguous.

---

Here are some similar contrasting examples with **in** and **for**:

> My vacation lasts **for a week**. [The duration of my vacation is one week.]
>
> My vacation begins **in the middle of the week**. [The starting day of my vacation is Wednesday or close to Wednesday.]
>
> My vacation begins **next week**. [The starting day of my vacation is one of the days in the following week.]

---

> I watched the groundhog every day **for a year**.
>
> I only saw the groundhog twice **in the past year**.
>
> I watched the groundhog **last year**. [Possibly as an ongoing activity lasting all year, possibly just once or twice during the year.]

---

> The next *Star Wars* movie is scheduled to come out **in 2019**.
>
> The next *Star Wars* movie is scheduled to come out **in December, 2019**.
>
> I worked for George Lucas **for six years**. [The duration was six years.]
>
> I worked for George Lucas **in 1986**. [My employment began and ended within 1986; possibly I had several terms of employment within 1986.]
>
> I saw George Lucas **last week**. [I saw him one or more times during the week of October 6–12.]

---

Comment: What is the difference between "next month" and "in the next month"?

Comment: So if I said "I will work in the next month", that would mean that I would work from a point of the next month and till the end of it, am I right? Honestly I stll cannot grasp the difference between "next month" and "in the next month". Could you eleborate on your explanation? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I just added a new section at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Today is October the 18th. If you say

> I will work **next month**

that means that you will work at some point in November.
If you say

> I will work **in the next month**

that means that you will work at some point in the period from October the 18th to November the 18th.
And to say

> I will work **for the next month**

means that you will work throughout the whole period from October the 18th to November the 18th.

Comment: This is correct.